# I2C - Read specific data register (Raspberry Pi 3+ Python)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi3, i2c

I have an assembly between a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (OS Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 buster) and a gas analyser (the gas analyser sensor use I2C), so i tried to communicate with it via my Raspberry.

On my linux terminal, my sensor is correctly identified at address "0X2D" via the `i2cdetect -y 1` command:

[image]

This sensor stores various data in a total of 26 registers (from 0x00 to 0x1A). My goal would be to be able to access via python code (Python 3.7.3) the values of any register. As stated in the sensor user manual, in order to read register X, it is necessary to write "empty" to this directory X of sensor 0X2D and then make a read request to sensor 0X2D.

Extract from the sensor manual:

[image]

Unfortunately, both via the Linux terminal (using the i2cget/set functions of the i2c-tools library) and via python code (using the smbus2 library), I have never managed to query a specific register, I always start from the first register 0X00.

On Linux, when I interrogate the sensor (which allows sequential reading) several times in a row after writing to first register 0x00, it returns the values of the successive registers (starting from the first register 0x00). These values seem to be correct because I get the correct serial number of the sensor which is stored in the registers from 0x13 to 0x19).
[image: Values returned by first registers]

But when I try to start from another register (0x02 for example), it restarts from 0x00 register :
[image: Non-success of starting from 0X02 register]

Am I making a mistake or is this the normal behaviour of such a sensor?

As far as the python part is concerned, I have not been able to find any code examples (or libraries) that allow you to make "empty" writes to a register in order to be able to read the value of this register afterwards.

Comment: Result of i2cdetect -y 1 command` Please do not post images of text. `Extract from the sensor manual` Please post what sensor exactly and if possible a link to full documentation. `ter : Non-success of starting from 0X02 register` Please do not post images of text. Please post text as text.

Comment: where do you get "empty"? It says you write the register address and then read that register. Please post your code.

Comment: You are not passing data-address ot i2cget. It's `i2cget -y 1 0x2d 0x02`.

Comment: To @KamilCuk : Please find the sensor documentation : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NIsuTNZL6_IWVth5GzuRGDNMN7J0Zgaq/view?usp=share_link

Comment: To @stark : To get a specific register data, it's necessary to send the I2C address with the R/W bit set to write and the register adress set to the desired register address. When i take a look to the smbus2 python library, all write methods ask a data to write at a specific register. As mentionned in the sensor manual, i need to access the register adress with R/W bit set to 0 (write mode) with no data (before reading data from this register).

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing data-address to i2cget. See man page.

```
i2cget -y 1 0x2d 0x02
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. I forgot to mention that whichever register is queried with i2cget, the sensor returns the value of the first register 0x00.

The only way i found to get values from all register is to use "i2cget -y 1 0x2d" command, and each iteration increase the register adress.

For example :
i2cset -y 1 0x2d 0x00 | i2cget -y 1 0x2d #Returns data of 0x00 register | i2cget -y 1 0x2d #Returns data of 0x01 register etc.

If i point a specific register, first register is read.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you are not passing data-address to i2cget.  `If i point a specific register, first register is read` How do you "point" it?

Comment: To @KamilCuk : I'm not sure to understand your answer.
In i2c-tools documentation, I found this for i2c get : i2cget [-f] [-y] i2cbus chip-address [data-address [mode]]. So i tried to reach directly 0x02 data adress on bus 1 on my sensor with the following : 'i2cget -y 1 0x2d 0x02'. I found that whichever register was pointed to, the value of the first register was returned. However, when I omitted to specify the register, each time the i2cget function was called, the register queried was incremented.

Comment: try: `i2cget -y 1 0x2d 0 w`. If not, post your python code. I do not think you can "just read" with i2cget.